# docker hub automated build does not use cache, does this mean layers are regenerated every time and that requires docker clients to redownload?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have noticed that docker hub automated build does not use cache.

I guess that's because they do the builds on different machines and cache can not be shared between them.

So that would mean that every time I push to my git repo, docker hub regenerates all layers, even if they are identical with last time? and that would require docker clients to redownload those layers that were regenerated?

So in practice, should I prefer building locally(or in a CI machine like jenkins) and push to docker hub, rather than using docker hub automated builds?